# Trying to line up bootstrap rails text_area vertically versus horizontal

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, devise

I'm a newbie here but I have yet to find any answers. My f.text_area :summary portion of my form is being pushed to the right and above the rest of my form and I can't correct it. I want it to be positioned inline below "topic". I've tried a number of different methods to correct the issue to no avail. Code below. Thanks. I'm using devise and bootstrap.

```
<div class="container new-pit">

<div class="panel-heading new-pit">Sign Up</div>

<%= render 'devise/shared/error_messages', obj: @pit %>

<%= simple_form_for(@pit) do |f| %>
<div class="panel-body new-pit">
    <div class="form-group new-pit">
        <%= f.label :topic %>
        <%= f.text_field :topic %>

        <%= f.label :summary %>
        <%= f.text_area :summary %>

        <h5>Upload Image</h5>
        <%= f.file_field :image %>

        <%= f.label :video %> 
        <%= f.text_field :video_url %></div>
 <div class="form-actions">
<%= f.submit "Start Pit" %>
</div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post a very simple layout/wireframe of what you're looking for? I can try and help if I have a better idea of what you want it to look like.

Comment: Thanks settheline but I ended up using this link - http://www.peoplecancode.com/tutorials/styling-devise-forms-with-twitter-bootstrap to figure it out. My issues had more to do with my inexperience with bootstrap than anything. I ended up revamping just about everything to make it more clean and responsive.